# Xcode 4.2- Storing a view in a detached Nib file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I am trying to create a fairly standard UI for an iOS app, a tab controller with one of the tabs having a navigation controller on it. The navigation controller will connect a few other views.

I want to add detached nib files such that all of my view are not sitting in the main storyboard file (Apple recommends doing this). I have tried following the instructions here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW33

Unfortunately I cannot find the "Nib Name" attribute for my view controller anywhere in the interface builder. I'm wondering if this has perhaps been removed from Xcode 4.2 as I can find information on doing this in older version of Xcode. Either way, if somebody could tell me how to use a detached nib file for what I am doing, that would be extremely helpful. Yes, I have googled all around and have not yet found anything that works.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

I am doing this from the storyboard. I've attached a screenshot now showing what I am trying to do. The nib with the view is called View2.xib. You can see from my screenshot that I only have "Title" and "Identifier" where "Nib Name" should be listed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPJse.png

Comment: As I understand it, storyboards end up as multiple nibs anyway. I'm curious, where did you see Apple recommend this approach of combining storyboards with your own explicitly external nibs?

Comment: See step 6: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH104-SW1 (perhaps their docs are just out of date?)

Comment: That doc is not about using storyboards. I don't think what you are trying to do here is necessary or possible with storyboards. You could, of course, use multiple storyboards, if you really need that.

Comment: I don't really need to do it. I just thought that it was the proper thing to do. I'm new to iOS dev so I'll take your word on it. Thanks!

Comment: I have the exact problem trying to create customized tableview cells on a seperate nib file...

Answer (score 1):

- If you are creating the view controller using Objective-C code, you pass the nib name to the `-[UIViewController initWithNibName:bundle:]` method when you create the view controller.
- If you are putting the view controller in the same XIB as the view it will control, you don't need to set the nib name.  Just connect the view controller's view outlet to the view it will control.
- If you are putting the view controller in some XIB `test.xib`, and you want it to load another XIB `other.xib`, you set the nib name in the Attributes Inspector while the view controller is selected:

[image: nib name field in IB]

Comment: I still don't have it working, see my update above. Thanks so far though.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I am using is to load an external Nib as a subview of the view in the storyboard. In viewDidLoad, do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyNib" bundle:nil];
    UIView* subview = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.view addSubview:subview];
    [subview setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    NSDictionary *viewsDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subview);
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[subview]|"
               options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[subview]|"
               options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDict]];

}
```